# SQLite: avoiding cycles in depth-limited recursive CTE

Tags: sqlite, recursion, common-table-expression

I'm using a recursive Common Table Expression in SQLite to traverse a graph. How can I avoid cycles in the traversal while also limiting the depth of the search?

For example, here's a very basic graph, represented as an edge list, with 3 nodes (in my case, the graph is directed but most edges are linked in both directions, similar to what's shown below):

```sql
sqlite> CREATE TABLE edges (source INTEGER, target INTEGER, label TEXT);
sqlite> INSERT INTO edges VALUES (1, 2, "down");
sqlite> INSERT INTO edges VALUES (2, 1, "up");
sqlite> INSERT INTO edges VALUES (2, 3, "down");
sqlite> INSERT INTO edges VALUES (3, 2, "up");
```

I could recursively find all children of node `1` with a maximum depth of 5 as follows (`level` is the depth of traversal):

```sql
sqlite> WITH RECURSIVE children(id, level) AS
   ...>   (SELECT 1, 0
   ...>    UNION SELECT target, children.level+1
   ...>            FROM edges
   ...>            JOIN children ON edges.source = children.id
   ...>           WHERE children.level < 5)
   ...> SELECT * FROM children;
1|0
2|1
1|2
3|2
2|3
1|4
3|4
2|5
```

Note that, for instance, node `1` is traversed 3 times with paths `1` (depth=0), `1,2,1` (depth=2), and either `1,2,3,2,1` or `1,2,1,2,1` (depth=4). If I'd used `UNION ALL`, I'd get some more (e.g., both `1,2,1,2,1` and `1,2,3,2,1`).

My problems are thus:

- `UNION` (as opposed to `UNION ALL`) does not filter all the duplicates because the depth is stored in the accumulated rows, so it only filters rows with the same descendant AND depth
- Removing the depth constraint would theoretically allow `UNION` to avoid duplicates, but without a `LIMIT` or some other bound, it would make the search go into infinite recursion (not to mention the fact that I'd lose the ability to do depth-limited traversals)

Also note that I'm using SQLite without extensions (via Python), so there are no array operations or other features that might help out. I'll provide a solution I came up with as an answer below, but I hope someone else knows a better one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By encoding the visited nodes on each row, one can avoid cycling on a node within a single traversal. If the node names are predictable, such as integers, then a simple delimited list will work:

```sql
sqlite> WITH RECURSIVE children(id, path, level) AS
   ...>   (SELECT 1, ",1,", 0  -- initial ',' is so instr() check below works
   ...>    UNION ALL SELECT target, children.path || target || ",", children.level+1
   ...>                FROM edges
   ...>                JOIN children ON edges.source = children.id
   ...>               WHERE children.level < 5
   ...>                 AND NOT instr(children.path, "," || target || ","))
   ...> SELECT * FROM children;
1|,1,|0
2|,1,2,|1
3|,1,2,3,|2
```

This does not prevent traversing to the same node through different paths, though. Consider adding another row:

```sql
sqlite> INSERT INTO edges VALUES (1, 3, "down");
```

Then the statement above would produce the following results:

```sql
1|,1,|0
2|,1,2,|1
3|,1,3,|1
3|,1,2,3,|2
2|,1,3,2,|2
```

Also the use of string concatenation and substring checking might not be the most performant.